# full outer join or right outer join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables as shown:

```
cat_id | cat_name
1      | free
2      | semi-paid
3      | premium
```

---

```
payment_id | user_id | cat_id
1          | 1       | 1
2          | 1       | 4
```

---

I want to query result like below

```
payment_id | user_id | cat_name
1          | 1       | free
null       | 1       | semi-paid
null       | 1       | premium
2          | 1       | null
```

I will show no payment icon in UI-on profile page- if **payment_id** is null. It means user_id=1 haven't used anything from semi-paid and premium categories.

I tried

```
SELECT payment_id, user_id, cat_name 
FROM payment 
FULL JOIN category 
  ON payment.cat_id 
WHERE user_id = 1
```

But I got a cartesian table :( Could you please help me?

Comment: So, do you need a row in the results for each unique category id for each unique user id? So between the unique Cat_id's in both payment and category you have 4 distinct cat_id, resulting in at least 4 rows for each user ID.  So if you didn't put the where clause (user_id = 1) and there were 2 user_id's defined in payment, you would need 8 rows minimum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d4b63/6)**

```
SELECT c.*, p.*, payment_id, user_id, cat_name
FROM category c
LEFT JOIN payment p
  ON c.cat_id = p.cat_id
 AND p.user_id = 1
UNION
SELECT c.*, p.*, payment_id, user_id, cat_name
FROM category c
RIGHT JOIN payment p
  ON c.cat_id = p.cat_id
 AND p.user_id = 1
```

**OUTPUT** focus on the last 3 columns

```
| cat_id |  cat_name | payment_id | user_id | cat_id | payment_id | user_id |  cat_name |
|--------|-----------|------------|---------|--------|------------|---------|-----------|
| (null) |    (null) |          2 |       1 |      4 |          2 |       1 |    (null) |
|      1 |      free |          1 |       1 |      1 |          1 |       1 |      free |
|      2 | semi-paid |     (null) |  (null) | (null) |     (null) |  (null) | semi-paid |
|      3 |   premium |     (null) |  (null) | (null) |     (null) |  (null) |   premium |
```

Comment: I deleted c.*-p.* then result is the same I just want. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to put your `user_id = 1` into your join condition or you will filter out the `NULL` rows.  Then all you need is `NULL` handling on `user_id`:

```
SELECT payment_id, COALESCE(user_id,1) as user_id, cat_name 
FROM payment p
FULL JOIN category c ON p.cat_id = c.cat_id 
                    AND p.user_id = 1
```

You could also do:

```
SELECT payment_id, 1 as user_id, cat_name 
FROM payment p
FULL JOIN category c ON p.cat_id = c.cat_id 
                    AND p.user_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 SELECT payment_id,
    case when payment_id is null 
         then 1 
         else user_id end user_Id, 
     cat_name 
    FROM payment 
    FULL outer JOIN category 
      ON payment.cat_id = category.cat_id;
```

Comment: I don't know if a hard-coded 1 is the right thing, but it's pretty incomprehensible what is desired.

Comment: I think user_id=2 cannot be reachable by this query